# regular expressions for a log file

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract unique files accessed from a log file. ie `"GET /socview/svspring01D.htm HTTP/1.1"*`

as I know the format I want to write a regular expression to extract all these files. I have done this one however I am not that happy with it. I would appreciate some help with this (I am new to programming)
Also as I can use `GET` as a starting point I don't wish to extract this for the dictionary, is there any ways of doing this? I am using a dictionary to count how many times each file was accessed.

```
match = re.search (r'^GET.*\.1' ,logfile)
```

Comment: Do you want to have the filenames only? Which programming language are you using?

Comment: python, yes just the file name only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regular expression:

```
^GET ([^\s]+).*$
```

And then match the first group `$1` to get the filename together with its path. The `^` character matches the beginning of the string, `([^\s]+)` matches every character (as much as possible) until the next white space character and forms a matching group. Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/pY7N0H/2

---

If you only want to match the filename without the path, you can use the following regular expression and look for the first match `$1` (It requires relative paths, starting with `/`):

```
^GET (?:\/[^\/\s]+)*\/([^\s]+).*$
```

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/SdXViV/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use ([**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/PxID4K/1/)):

```
(?:GET|POST)\s+(/\S+)
# GET or POST
# followed by whitespaces
# (capture / and no whitespaces at least once)
```

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'(?:GET|POST)\s+(/\S+)')

string = """
"GET /socview/svspring01D.htm HTTP/1.1"*
"GET /socvdsdiew/svspring0fsff323231D.htm HTTP/1.1"*
"GET /socvhdhdhdiew/svspring0323231D.htm HTTP/1.1"*
"POST /socddssdview/sveweweasd423232spring01D.htm HTTP/1.1"*
"""

files = rx.findall(string)
print(files)
# ['/socview/svspring01D.htm', '/socvdsdiew/svspring0fsff323231D.htm', '/socvhdhdhdiew/svspring0323231D.htm', '/socddssdview/sveweweasd423232spring01D.htm']
```